# Google Rest api to get primary mail

Tags: api, email

How to get the gmail primary mail using Google rest API.Currently i am using the GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages Rest API but that will give the social and promotion mail.I am referring this site:https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question with some more details like, the language you and if possible some code that you have already written.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this as a filter in your query when calling messages.list

[ in:inbox -category:{social promotions updates forums} ]

that only gives you the good stuff.  It's basically saying give me everything in the inbox apart from social, promotions, updates and forums.

Or in my inbox I also seem to have updates so you'd change to

[ in:inbox -category:{social promotions forums} ]

Cheers

John

Comment: great, also useful even after 6 years!  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty straight forward actually

We can query the messages by using labels. Labels are of two types System labels and User Labels.

For primary we can use System label called "INBOX" and get the emails that belong to that category. There are other system labels like CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS, CATEGORY_SOCIAL etc.

You can use the Try It! feature with Google to test it out.

Get labels:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list

For a given label, say INBOX in your case query the messages 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

You can also get the STARRED, CATEGORY_PERSONAL for starred and important emails from the inbox.

**Edited for sample code.** 
Java Code Sample available within the link, but a snippet here:

`public static void listLabels(Gmail service, String userId) throws IOException {
    ListLabelsResponse response = service.users().labels().list(userId).execute();
    List<Label> labels = response.getLabels();
    for (Label label : labels) {
      System.out.println(label.toPrettyString());
    }
  }`

Comment: Nice answer. Would be even better if you included some actual code or request examples here directly instead of only linking to the manual.